# What is the difference between wso2 and ESB?

Tags: architecture, wso2, components, esb, platform

What is the difference between **wso2** and **ESB**?

Is the **wso2** just a **ESB** type?

If the answer is no, what features does **wso2** have that does not have a **ESB**?

Is there a general architecture of **wso2** that shows all components and how they interact?

Answer (score 4):

WSO2 is a company. WSO2EI is a product offered by wso2 with ESB capabilities.

WSO2EI is the successor of WSO2ESB.

https://docs.wso2.com/display/EI620/Overview